# How to get a list of available vm sizes in an azure location

Tags: azure

I want to deploy a VM in microsoft's azure with a new size.
Usually I use a json template for the vm with size 'Standard_DS3'
Now I would like to have another one with size a3 'A3', but this causes an error

```
statusMessage:{"error":{"code":"InvalidParameter","target":"vmSize","message":"The value of parameter vmSize is invalid."}}
```

So I was wondering where can I find valid vm sizes for deployments in a location and the correct name for the deployment with a template file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you mentioned json templates in your question then I assume that you are using Azure Resource Manager to provision resources. If that's the case, you can use the following REST API endpoint to [list all available virtual machine sizes in a region](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt269440.aspx).

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/locations/{location}/vmSizes?api-version={api-version}
```

This information is accessible using Azure CLI, i.e.: `az vm list-sizes --location "eastus"`

You can also reference Microsoft documentation to see the list of [virtual machine sizes](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-size-specs/). Sounds like you need to use the "Large" size in your template to provision an A3 Standard VM.

Comment: I am using the azure cli on osx is the rest call also available in the client? so far I can't find it.

Comment: Yes, this functionality is available in the Azure CLI. For example, run `azure vm sizes --location "eastus"` to see all VM sizes available in the East US region. Before you run the command, make sure to enable Azure Resource Manager commands by running `azure config mode arm`.

Comment: YESSS. This is the perfect answer. In my case "azure vm sizes --location "westeurope"" .

Comment: @VassiliAltynikov - you should edit your answer with the cli command, rather than burying it in comments.

Answer (score 16):

One can list all vm-sizes available in specific location(e.g `westus`) from **Azure CLI 2.0** using following command

```
az vm list-sizes --location "westus"
```

Answer (score 9):

This isn´t always true. I´ve got into a situation where this command gives me a VM size that wasn´t truely avalaible for my location. This is a known issue of the Azure CLI.

Here is the statement from Azure support:

**Cause**: It is known that the command az vm list-sizes can expose sizes that are actually unavailable and we are working on that situation.

**Resolution:** The best option is to mitigate this is to cross check the information provided by that query with the restrictions that you have in the subscription that can be analyzed by the command az vm list-skus. For your scenario, you can see the SKU restrictions in West Europe by using the following:

```
az vm list-skus --location WestEurope --output table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Get-AzureRmVMSize commandlet in PowerShell. This doesn't change too often and I have a .NET library which contains a snapshot of those https://github.com/aloneguid/microsoft-azure-strongtyped